# Why does Stack Overflow wipe out your reputation when you register?

Tags: support, reputation, sign-up

I had some reputation built under an unregistered user, and when I registered I got reset to 1. What's up with that? Is there any way to get my reputation back?

Answer (score 5):

You now have a new account.

Flag one of your posts from your original unregistered account for moderator attention explaining that you'd like your accounts merging. Don't forget to include the id of the new account.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I registered, so I wrote to SO team and them, and the fixed it. However, it was more than one year ago, when user count of SO was significantly smaller.